# Is it possible to auto-connect iPad as an extended screen when it's connected to a MacOS laptop via USB-C?

Tags: macos, ipad, display, usb, sidecar

Use case:

*As* a user *I want to* connect iPad to a macbook laptop and iPad will become an external MacOS display immediately 
*so that* no user actions will not be required for daily basis usage.

Is there a solution for that, maybe automation or something?

- MacOS Ventura 13.5.2
- iPadOS 16.6

**UPD1**

Just came across onto this post (used "Sidecar" keyword) 
[Is it possible to automatically connect to Sidecar once my iPad is connected to the Mac through a USB cable?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/il8x0y/is_it_possible_to_automatically_connect_to/)

...will test it.